# Splitting a range of indexes into groups / islands using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

Splitting a range of indexes into groups using geometry nodes

I'm trying to split an object into groups / islands based on it's index value.

Example: The line has **25** indexes and I want to split it up into a **group / island that includes 5 indexes**.

**So each group / island will have 5 indexes**

```
Group 1 will include 0,1,2,3,4
Group 2 will include 5,6,7,8,9 
etc...
```

[image: img1]

What I tried but my logic isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assume you want this?

[image]

With *Modulo 5 > Equal 4* I delete the edges (every 5th one) and so I can make the split to the islands.

[image]

The problem with *Split Edges* seems to be that both sides of the edge are cut, so you get more "cuts" than you actually want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, Thanks!...